# /bin/sh: cl: command not found usig make within cygwin

Tags: windows, makefile, cygwin

I'm working with Intel Pin on a Windows 7 machine. As suggested on Pin user guide, I downloaded Cygwin with the packages I need, such as gcc, g++ and make, but when I try to execute the command "make" in order to build one tool (Insmix in this case, but it is the same with any other Pin tool) I get the following error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/IEUser/Downloads/pin-3.2-81205-msvc-windows/source/tools/Insmix'

cl /MT /EHs- /EHa- /wd4530 /DTARGET_WINDOWS /DBIGARRAY_MULTIPLIER=1 /nologo /Gy /Oi- /GR- /GS- /D__PIN__=1 /DPIN_CRT=1 /D_WINDOWS_H_PATH_="" /D__i386__ /DTARGET_IA32 /DHOST_IA32  /I../../../source/include/pin /I../../../source/include/pin/gen -I../../../extras/stlport/include -I../../../extras -I../../../extras/libstdc++/include -I../../../extras/crt/include -I../../../extras/crt -I../../../extras/crt/include/arch-x86 -I../../../extras/crt/include/kernel/uapi -I../../../extras/crt/include/kernel/uapi/asm-x86 /FIinclude/msvc_compat.h /I../../../extras/components/include /I../../../extras/xed-ia32/include/xed /I../../../source/tools/InstLib /O2  /c /Foobj-ia32/insmix.obj insmix.cpp

**/bin/sh: cl: command not found**

make[1]: *** [../../../source/tools/Config/makefile.default.rules:192: obj-ia32/insmix.obj] Error 127
```

I tried to Google it with no success. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thank you very much for you help

Comment: It looks like the make is trying to run a command 'cl', which is not in your path.   You can look if there is a cl command installed somewhere on your drive (and if it is, install it in your path), or check out makefile.default.rules, line 192 to see what it's trying to do.

Comment: As `cl` is not a program of any cygwin package, you need to verify if it should come from some other tool that you need ?

Answer (score 0):

*cl* is prettymuch a Microsoft tool. Install some Visual Studio version, and you'll have that *cl* tool somewhere in the *bin* directory in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\...\bin\` Now you set that directory in the environment Path variable. Voila. That works.